# Handle cancel button while using Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

When the cancel button on the camera is pressed it returns to its present activity however I would like it to go back to the previous screen (which is a fragment). [image: Camera]

[image: This is the button in question]

When I press the hard key [image: hard key] it returns as desired. This is done using `finish();`

EDIT: The code below is now working :)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data !=null && getInfo !=null){
        if(requestCode==0){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getAction() != null){
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
               if(theImage !=null && getInfo !=null && data!=null){
                   iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                   }
             }else{
                         finish();
             }
        }
        else if (requestCode == 1) {


            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


           if(picturePath !=null && getInfo !=null && data!=null){
              iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
           }//end if pic


    }else{
           finish();//returns as desired but does not work for the 'X' in the camera only hard key
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both return RESULT_CANCEL (0) as resultCode?

Comment: Thanks, could you further explain with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try testing against resultCode/requestCode first, something like this:

```
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null ) {
        ... now let's see use the picture at data
```

Remember that `resultCode` is the actuall Activity result and you should use RESULT_OK.

Also note that `requestCode` only makes sense when you have more than one call for `startActivityForResult` and each call for different purposes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although not the answer, this helped me extremely to find the problem, your tip was very helpful :)